# Generic Statment Running on Oracle SQL: DB Using Java

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I'm developing a system build in Java and using Oracle SQL DB.
Some users need to run statements on the DB directly (querying, updating, deleting etc.) but without accessing the DB themselves.

Therefore I'm trying to develop a code in which they'll run a statement and it will return the result to them from the DB.

Unfortunately, Every example online demands the developer to know the table, I need my solution to suit every query or any other statement they'll run.

Thanks In Advnace.

Here's a code example which demonstrates my problem:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

    while (rs.next()) {
        String coffeeName = rs.getString("COF_NAME");
        int supplierID = rs.getInt("SUP_ID");
        float price = rs.getFloat("PRICE");
        int sales = rs.getInt("SALES");
        int total = rs.getInt("TOTAL");
        System.out.println(coffeeName + ", " + supplierID +
                           ", " + price + ", " + sales +
                           ", " + total);
    }
```

Comment: It is better to give examples for such queries, and clarify your issue with the code you attached!

Comment: Why would the developer need to know the table? This is not a requirement of every example online.

Comment: Then How can I retrieve the result without the getInt("SOMTHING") of getFloat("SOMTHING") which obviestly are very specific to a table @LowKeyEnergy

Comment: @MohamedSweelam Can't attach my own cause of NDA... but I belive this code clarifies that a query on another table will simply fail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get the results based on the names of columns. If you don't know the column names, you can get the results by their index number.

```
Object x = resultSet.getObject(0);
```

You can also get info about the available columns:

```
ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html

```
ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();

while (resultSet.next()) {
    for (int i=1; i < metaData.getColumnCount(); i++) {
        Object x = resultSet.getObject(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: How? Can you please share an example?

Comment: added an example.

Comment: IS THERE A WAY TO GET THE COLUMN NAME?

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the results based on their index number.

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

while (rs.next()) {
    for (int i=1; i<rsmd.getColumnCount(); i++) {
        String result = rs.getString(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a generic SQL interface. When I was in that need, I would look for an "open source java command line tool to execute SQL statements" or "open source java command line SQL Client". Check the license and hook up on what is available in that tool. 
Will save you a lot of nasty details.

When you are lucky such a tool supports also listing of all databases, tables, list table info, SQL statement history etc.

It is not the direct answer to your question, but it might save you a lot of work.